# Handling the back button with parameter in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I create one page Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App.
i want when click on button navigate back to page came from.

```
    private void backbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {                
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

the problem is, i want back some parameter like id=10&name=test

i can do it when navigate to Uri

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(page1), "id=1");
```

or

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("myapp:///id=1"));
```

but there is no function to do it

```
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {                
            rootFrame.GoBack("some parameter id=10");
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem for me as well, so I in such a scenario I came up with the idea to create a static class where I put my data which I need to pass back. On the page which you navigate from, you can write the data in OnNavigatedFrom, and then on the page where you navigate to, you can read that data in the OnNavigatedTo method, if the NavigationMode is NavigationMode.Back.

Comment: can use this method to pass data to external application that call page1.xaml and pass data back ?

Comment: i try your scenario, now how do i write data on OnNavigatedFrom and read it on OnNavigatedTo ?

Comment: thanks,i did it.i want back data from external app like 'app2' to 'app1'.do you know how to do that ?

Comment: I hope I could help! That's another question, please ask it as well, rather than discussing it here ;) Also, accept it if you found it useful, so others looking for this will click on it and see the solution.